# When do I get experience while fighting with companions?

Tags: fallout-3

I am currently traveling with Fawkes and Dogmeat and sometimes, when killing enemies, I do not get experience points. I am assuming that I need to inflict a certain percentage of the damage to get the experience - but how much is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal at least 30% of the damage necessary to kill an opponent to receive the experience for the kill.